# SignalR JS command doesn't execute on websockets first time (vb.net)

Tags: javascript, vb.net, websocket, signalr

So when I visit my page and I set the video mode using this:

```
$("#pushStreamButton").click(function () {
    if (initialized) {
        var channelSelected = $("#channelSelect").val();
        var gameNameEntered = $("#gameName").val();
        var channelNameEntered = $("#channelName").val();
        if (gameNameEntered.length < 1) return;
        $("#goLiveWindow").dialog("close");
        serverHub.server.setVideoMode(channelSelected, gameNameEntered, "", channelNameEntered);
    }
});
```

and this is in the backend

```
Public Sub setVideoMode(ByVal mode As String, ByVal details As String, ByVal socialMessage As String, ByVal channel As String)
    Dim user As FrontPageUser = Connections.matchFirst(Connections.frontPageUsers, Context.ConnectionId)
    If user Is Nothing Then Return
    If mode = "youtube" Then
        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/images/streamavatar.gif"))
        Catch Ex As Exception
            Console.Write(Ex)
        End Try
    End If
```

This functions as expected, it does it's job, however I have a button that reverts the channel back to the default youtube

```
$("#stopStreamButton").click(function () {

        serverHub.server.setVideoMode("youtube", "", "", "");

});
```

After changing the channel using the first button, clicking the second button doesn't do anything, it doesn't even seem to attempt to execute the command, which is bizarre. However if I reload the page the button functions correctly and the channel is reverted.

This issue also isn't present when using SSE/longpolling/foreverframe, only when using websockets as the transport. I'm treading relatively unknown waters with websockets, and I've tried debugging the javascript and the backend code - the javascript doesn't seem to execute correctly, but it doesn't spout any errors, and it never reaches the backend.

If anybody knows why this happens and could explain where I'm going wrong, it'd be appreciated.

Additional: after digging further, it actually appears to stop all functions from the java side and after a while it seems to disconnect and force a refresh, not sure what is causing it, but I know it has to be related to websockets.

edit --

Upon debugging cause, it appears to be linked to another function which sends a push notification to subscribers, when I disable this function it works without hanging and blocking commands, but when this function is initialized it hangs, seemingly after the function has completed

```
Shared Function sendPushFox(username, pushDetails) As String
    Dim avatar = Utils.getAvatarPath(username)
    If avatar.Contains("/forum/download/file.php?avatar=") OrElse avatar.Contains("/images/solaire.png") Then
        Try
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://foo.com" & avatar, HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/images/streamavatar.gif"))
        Catch ex As Exception
            ChatProcessor.postNewMessage(Nothing, Nothing, ChatMessage.MessageType.Channel_Mod, "Problem downloading streamer avatar." & ex.ToString)
        End Try
    Else
        Try
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(avatar, HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/images/streamavatar.gif"))
        Catch ex As Exception
            ChatProcessor.postNewMessage(Nothing, Nothing, ChatMessage.MessageType.Channel_Mod, "Problem downloading streamer avatar." & ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End If
    Dim query As String = "SELECT subscribeid FROM custom_user_data WHERE NOT subscribeid = ' ';"
    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(Utils.connectionString) : connection.Open()
    Dim command As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    Dim regList As New List(Of String)
    Do While reader.Read
        regList.Add(reader.GetString(0))
        ' IO.File.AppendAllText(Utils.serverPath & "errorlog.txt", reg1)
    Loop
    connection.Close()
    Dim query2 As String = "SELECT p256dh FROM custom_user_data WHERE NOT p256dh = ' ';"
    Dim connection2 As New MySqlConnection(Utils.connectionString) : connection2.Open()
    Dim command2 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query2, connection2)
    Dim reader2 As MySqlDataReader = command2.ExecuteReader()
    Dim regList2 As New List(Of String)
    Do While reader2.Read
        regList2.Add(reader2.GetString(0))
        ' IO.File.AppendAllText(Utils.serverPath & "errorlog.txt", reg1)
    Loop
    connection2.Close()
    Dim query3 As String = "SELECT authsecret FROM custom_user_data WHERE NOT authsecret = ' ';"
    Dim connection3 As New MySqlConnection(Utils.connectionString) : connection3.Open()
    Dim command3 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query3, connection3)
    Dim reader3 As MySqlDataReader = command3.ExecuteReader()
    Dim regList3 As New List(Of String)
    Do While reader3.Read
        regList3.Add(reader3.GetString(0))
        ' IO.File.AppendAllText(Utils.serverPath & "errorlog.txt", reg1)
    Loop
    connection3.Close()
    Dim reg1 = regList.ToArray
    Dim reg2 = regList2.ToArray
    Dim reg3 = regList3.ToArray
    Dim payload = "{   ""title"": ""foo bar"",     ""body"": """ & username.name.ToString & " playing " & pushDetails.ToString & """, ""icon"" : ""https://foo.com/images/streamavatar.gif"" }"
    For i As Integer = 0 To reg1.Length - 1
        Dim webPushClient = New WebPushClient()

        Dim subject = "https://foo.com"
        Dim vapidKeys As VapidDetails = VapidHelper.GenerateVapidKeys()
        Dim vapidDetails = New VapidDetails(subject, vapidKeys.PublicKey, vapidKeys.PrivateKey)
        Try
            Console.WriteLine("Public {0}", vapidKeys.PublicKey)
            Console.WriteLine("Private {0}", vapidKeys.PrivateKey)
            Dim subscription = New PushSubscription(reg1(i), reg2(i), reg3(i))

            webPushClient.SetGCMAPIKey("key here")
            webPushClient.SendNotification(subscription, payload, vapidDetails)

        Catch Ex As Exception
            Console.Write(Ex)
        End Try
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

So, it's a clash with websockets, since it functions on longpolling and etc but I'm still not sure why, and it only affects the user who calls the function.

Strangely enough this appears to hang after the "next" which happens here

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To reg1.Length - 1
            webPushClient.SetGCMAPIKey("key here")
            webPushClient.SendNotification(subscription, payload, vapidDetails)
        Next
```

it functions completely fine, but once it reaches the end of the for, it just never continues, it does literally nothing after Next, no errors, nothing happens, set breaks and results are as expected, I'm just baffled as to why it doesn't continue, and only using websockets trasports, longpolling and etc is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out, it turns out that websockets don't like the non asynchronous communication made from the command

```
webPushClient.SendNotification(subscription, payload, vapidDetails)
```

Fortunately the webPush lib has an async and changing it to

```
webPushClient.SendNotificationAsync(subscription, payload, vapidDetails)
```

fixed everything.